# Testing mailers with Rspec and factory_bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, actionmailer, rspec3, ruby-on-rails-6.1

- Hey guys, i need help, am new to testing and am testing my mailer but i do not understand y am getting this error when i run my tests.
- 'expected `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 2'
- The emails are triggered by the `after_create` hook
- My code is working as expected but the tests are failing. Anyone with help is appreciated.

**verfiy_mailer.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class VerifyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def verification_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'verification code')
  end
end
```

**verify_mailer_spec.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'
# include ActiveJob::TestHelper

RSpec.describe VerifyMailer, type: :mailer do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:mail) { VerifyMailer.verification_email(user).deliver_now }

  it 'renders the receiver email' do
    expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])
  end
  it 'renders the subject' do
    expect(mail.subject).to eq('verification code')
  end
  it 'renders the sender email' do
    expect(mail.from).to eq(['mutebigod10@gmail.com'])
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :send_user_otp
  attr_writer :login

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable ,

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, authentication_keys: [:username]
  has_many :payments
  validates :email, :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*\z/,
                                 message: ' only allow letter, number, underscore and punctuation marks' }

  # Loggin with user_name
  def login
    @login || username
  end

  def send_user_otp
    unverify!
    otp = generate_codes
    update_column(:otp_code, otp)
    VerifyMailer.verification_email(self).deliver_now
    touch(:otp_sent_at)
  end

  def unverify!
    update_column(:verified, false)
  end

  def generate_codes
    loop do
      code = rand(0o00000..999_999).to_s
      break code unless code.length != 6
    end
  end
end
```

- I have added   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test to enviroment/test.rb
- am also using factory_bot_rails to create user

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}" }
    password { '!Mutebi2' }
    password_confirmation { '!Mutebi2' }
  end
end
```

Comment: You should not have to manually execute the job que - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers

Comment: Is `User#send_user_otp` triggered by a create/save callback perhaps? If so then `VerifyMailer#verification_email` would be called once on user create and once in the spec itself. Side note: If you use `deliver_now` instead of `deliver_later` in the test then `perform_enqueued_jobs` is not need.

Comment: yeah, User#send_user_otp is triggered after the user is created by devise with this callback `after_create :send_user_otp`

Comment: i understand the problem should be this hook now i have to make some research to see how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in most cases, the computer is doing exactly what you told it to do:

```rb
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:mail) { VerifyMailer.verification_email(user).deliver_now }
```

Creating the `user` with `FactoryBot` triggers any/all callbacks:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :send_user_otp
```

So `create(:user)` calls `:send_user_otp` after it's created.

Then you send another email with `VerifyMailer.verification_email(user).deliver_now`

Hence why `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` changes by 2.

---

In your `VerifyMailer` tests, you are testing the attributes of the email, so you don't need the user to actually be saved or the email to actually be sent.

If you need an instance of the email, just remove `deliver_now`. And you can `build` instead of `create` the `user`:

```rb
RSpec.describe VerifyMailer, type: :mailer do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  let(:mail) { VerifyMailer.verification_email(user) }

  it 'renders the receiver email' do
    expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])
  end
  it 'renders the subject' do
    expect(mail.subject).to eq('verification code')
  end
  it 'renders the sender email' do
    expect(mail.from).to eq(['mutebigod10@gmail.com'])
  end
end
```

In your `User` tests, you can verify that creating a user also creates the email:

```rb
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }

  describe "after create" do
    it "calls #send_user_otp" do
      expect(user).to receive(:send_user_otp)
    end
  end

  describe "#send_user_otp" do
    it "calls VerifyMailer.verification_email" do
      expect(VerifyMailer).to receive(:verification_email).with(user)

      user.send(:send_user_otp)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I'm not actually testing `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` at all. That's a service or request test, which should be based on a full implementation, e.g.:

When this form is filled out:

- A User record gets created
- An email gets sent <= here is where you test that the email queue got an email

Your `User` model isn't responsible for `VerifyMailer`, `ApplicationMailer` and any other code that handles `delver_now`, it's only responsible for calling `VerifyMailer` and handing it the `user` instance.

And `VerifyMailer` isn't responsible for handling delivery, it creates the email and passes it off to `ActionMailer`.

Keep your tests focused on the responsibilities of your code, it will make them less brittle.

If you change something in your `ActionMailer` setup, you don't want `User` tests to start to fail.